# Set File datasource property to restrict start folder

Tags: content-editor, fieldtype

I am using the `File` field type to allow a content editor to upload a new file, or select an existing file.

I wish to restrict where a file can be chosen from, so I have set the datasource of the field to a folder in my Media Library:

```
DataSource=/sitecore/Media Library/Images/
```

Now, when I click `Open File` on a content item, I get the error:

[image]

How can I specify a 'start folder' for the File control to point at? 
Thanks

Comment: try lowercase media library: `/sitecore/media library/Images` .
also what do you have in logs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to set in this way DataSource,

you just need to set DataSource on template field to : media library path (ex: "/sitecore/media library/Images/Social/Connector")

[image]

When you will open you will see :

[image]

One small issue that I remarked is Search tab is before Browse tab.

Comment: Have you found a solution to the issue of the the search tab being first?

Answer (score 4):

The "DataSource" is only for selection fields (Droplist, treelist and so on) - other field types only support a path, like Sitecore Climber writes.

Further explanations are available in the Data definition cook book (old, but still relevant :))
https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/datadefinitioncookbook-a4.pdf